# Pandas append multiple columns for a single one

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use pandas to append multiple KPI values per single customer efficiently?

A join of the `pivoted` df with the `customers` df makes some problems because the country is the index of the pivoted data frame and the nationality is not in the index.

```
countryKPI = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Austria','Germany', 'Germany', 'Austria'],
                           'indicator':['z','x','z','x'],
                           'value':[7,8,9,7]})
customers = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['first','second'],
                           'nationality':['Germany','Austria'],
                           'value':[7,8]})
```

See the desired result in pink:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could counter the mismatch in the categories through [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data=countryKPI, index=['country'], columns=['indicator'])
df.index.name = 'nationality'    
customers.merge(df['value'].reset_index(), on='nationality', how='outer')
```

[image]

Data:

```
countryKPI = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Austria','Germany', 'Germany', 'Austria'],
                           'indicator':['z','x','z','x'],
                           'value':[7,8,9,7]})
customers = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['first','second'],
                           'nationality':['Slovakia','Austria'],
                           'value':[7,8]})
```

---

The problem appears to be that you have got `CategoricalIndex` in your `DF` resulting from the `pivot` operation and when you perform `reset_index` on that complains you of that error.

Simply do reverse engineering as in check the `dtypes` of `countryKPI` and `customers` Dataframes and wherever there is `category` mentioned, convert those columns to their `string` representation via `astype(str)`

---

**Reproducing the Error and Countering it:**

Assume the `DF` to be the above mentioned:

```
countryKPI['indicator'] = countryKPI['indicator'].astype('category')
countryKPI['country'] = countryKPI['country'].astype('category')
customers['nationality'] = customers['nationality'].astype('category')

countryKPI.dtypes
country      category
indicator    category
value           int64
dtype: object

customers.dtypes
customer         object
nationality    category
value             int64
dtype: object
```

After `pivot` operation:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data=countryKPI, index=['country'], columns=['indicator'])
df.index
CategoricalIndex(['Austria', 'Germany'], categories=['Austria', 'Germany'], ordered=False, 
                  name='country', dtype='category')
# ^^ See the categorical index
```

When you perform `reset_index` on that:

```
df.reset_index()
```

> TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not
>   already an existing category

To counter that error, simply cast the categorical columns to `str` type.

```
countryKPI['indicator'] = countryKPI['indicator'].astype('str')
countryKPI['country'] = countryKPI['country'].astype('str')
customers['nationality'] = customers['nationality'].astype('str')
```

Now, the `reset_index` part works and even the `merge` too.

Comment: interesting and simpler. But http://imgur.com/a/PeCyh why do I get several other values for the initial dataset (0,1,2,3)?

Comment: I see - your latest edit invalidates my last comment.

Comment: However, still the problem applies that: cannot insert an item into a Categorical Index that i not already an existing category

Comment: Maybe the sub-columns of `value` is in categorical format. Try to convert them to `string` via: `df['value'].columns = df['value'].columns.astype(str)` Then, do the merge operation.

Comment: Is object ok as a dtype? because the error occurs there: `df['value'].reset_index()`

Comment: `object` dtype is fine. But did you do the steps I mentioned before? It should work then.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_pivoted = countryKPI.pivot_table(index='country', 
                              columns='indicator', 
                              values='value', 
                              fill_value=0)
print (df_pivoted)    
indicator  x  z
country        
Austria    7  7
Germany    8  9

print (pd.concat([customers.set_index('nationality'), df_pivoted], axis=1))
        customer  value  x  z
Austria   second      8  7  7
Germany    first      7  8  9                       


print (pd.concat([customers.set_index('nationality'), df_pivoted], axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'nationality'})
         [['customer','nationality','value','x','z']])

  customer nationality  value  x  z
0   second     Austria      8  7  7
1    first     Germany      7  8  9
```

EDIT by comments:

Problem is `dtypes` of columns `customers.nationality` and `countryKPI.country` is `category` and if some categories are missing, it raise error:

> ValueError: incompatible categories in categorical concat

Solution find common categories by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) and then [set_categories](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#setting-categories):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

countryKPI = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Austria','Germany', 'Germany', 'Austria'],
                           'indicator':['z','x','z','x'],
                           'value':[7,8,9,7]})
customers = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['first','second'],
                           'nationality':['Slovakia','Austria'],
                           'value':[7,8]})

customers.nationality = customers.nationality.astype('category')
countryKPI.country = countryKPI.country.astype('category')

print (countryKPI.country.cat.categories)
Index(['Austria', 'Germany'], dtype='object')

print (customers.nationality.cat.categories)
Index(['Austria', 'Slovakia'], dtype='object')

all_categories =countryKPI.country.cat.categories.union(customers.nationality.cat.categories)
print (all_categories)
Index(['Austria', 'Germany', 'Slovakia'], dtype='object')

customers.nationality = customers.nationality.cat.set_categories(all_categories)
countryKPI.country = countryKPI.country.cat.set_categories(all_categories)
```

```
df_pivoted = countryKPI.pivot_table(index='country', 
                              columns='indicator', 
                              values='value', 
                              fill_value=0)
print (df_pivoted)    
indicator  x  z
country        
Austria    7  7
Germany    8  9
Slovakia   0  0        

print (pd.concat([customers.set_index('nationality'), df_pivoted], axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'nationality'})
         [['customer','nationality','value','x','z']])

  customer nationality  value  x  z
0   second     Austria    8.0  7  7
1      NaN     Germany    NaN  8  9
2    first    Slovakia    7.0  0  0
```

If need better performance, instead [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df_pivoted1 = countryKPI.groupby(['country','indicator'])
                        .mean()
                        .squeeze()
                        .unstack()
                        .fillna(0)
print (df_pivoted1)
indicator    x    z
country            
Austria    7.0  7.0
Germany    8.0  9.0
Slovakia   0.0  0.0
```

**Timings**:

```
In [177]: %timeit countryKPI.pivot_table(index='country', columns='indicator', values='value', fill_value=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.24 ms per loop

In [178]: %timeit countryKPI.groupby(['country','indicator']).mean().squeeze().unstack().fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: That nearly works - but I get the error of incompatible categories in categorical concat

Comment: Problem is with real data, right? Smale works perfectly, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#merging this one `In this case the categories are not the same and so an error is raised:` might be a clue

Comment: One solution is convert `category` column to `string` or add missing categories. Which columns are dtype `category?`

Comment: the nationality columns used for the join

Comment: Try `customers.nationality = customers.nationality.astype(str)`

Comment: I simulated problem, give me a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123930/discussion-between-georg-heiler-and-jezrael).